# What is the random tape?

Tags: public-key, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I am reading the paper "Toward plaintext-aware public-key encryption without random oracles" by Bellare and Palacio. So I can't understand what is the tape and random tape?

Answer (score 4):

Tape is a basic concept from [Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine).

The random tape is [the tape with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitape_Turing_machine) random bits on it.